# Prove that if $U$ and $W$ are 3-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^5$ then $U ∩ W$ is non-trivial

Tags: linear-algebra

I said that since a 3-dimensional subspace is the span of 3 linearly independent vectors then $U$ and $W$ must be linearly independent.

Since $U$ and $W$ are linearly independent then they span the entire 3-dimensional space.

Since $U$ and $W$ span the entire space, they intersect everywhere.

Therefore, $U \cap W$ is non-trivial for every vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ except for the null vector.

This was my reasoning but can anybody tell me if my thinking is correct. I feel like I am missing something since I did not make use of $\mathbb{R}^5$.

Answer (score 1):

Choose bases $A=\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ and $B=\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ for $U$ and $W$ respectively. If $A \cap B$ is nonempty we are done. Suppose not. Then $A \cup B$ contains $6$ distinct vectors in $\mathbb{R}^5$, a $5$ dimensional space, so they must be linearly dependent. This means there exist scalars $\lambda_i, \mu_i$ not all equal to zero such that
$$\sum_i \lambda_i u_i +\sum_i \mu_i w_i=0.$$
Taking the right sum to the other side we see that $\sum_i \lambda_i u_i \in W$. Since it is also in $U$, it is in $U \cap W$. It is nonzero because if it would be zero then the $\lambda_i$ would all be zero and by linear independence of the $u_i$ and the $\mu_i$ would be zero as well by linear independence of the $w_i$.  This shows $U \cap W$ contains a nonzero element.

Answer (score -1):

Recall that $\dim(U\cap V) + \dim(U+V) = \dim U + \dim V=6$. If the intersection was trivial, $U+V$ would have dimension $6$, which of course is impossible.

Comment: Is this an expansion to my proof or am I totally off base? This makes sense but I feel like mine also does.

Comment: @Nic No, it is false that $U$ and $W$ are linearly independent, since else they would, again, have sum of dimension $6$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why $dim(U∩V)+dim(U+V)$ is being done. Why are you added U and V? Is it because they are linearly dependent?

Comment: @qbert Have you ever heard of (linearly) independent subspaces? Two subspaces are independent if and only if their intersection is trivial; for more than two the condition is a bit more complicated, but for finite dimensional spaces it is equivalent to saying that the dimension of the sum is the sum of the dimensions.

Comment: @egreg I did not when I took the course, and it isn't used in the linear algebra course I am TA-ing for right now. If it is common place and what the op meant, I will edit my answer and delete my comment

Comment: @qbert As egreg notes, it's perfectly common practice to say two subspaces are linearly independent.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I still haven’t heard it but if you say so I believe it